# R creating variable with satisfying condition

Tags: r

Help sought from anyone.

I have a household survey data set named h2004 and would like to create a variable equals to another variable that satisfy certain condition. Here I have put a sample of observations.

```
cq15      expen
10     0.4616136
10     1.538712
11     2.308068
11     0.384678
12     2.576797822
12     5.5393632
13     5.4624276
14     2.6158104
14     20.157127
```

and I tried the following command:

```
h2004$crops[h2004$cq15>=12 & h2004$cq15<=14]=h2004$expen
```

and this produces wrong results in R as I know the correct result from using Stata. In the original data set, the above command takes values of 'expen' even when `cq15<12` and replaces the observations against `cq15>=12 & cq15<=14`.

I also tried with filter option of dplyr that correctly subset the data frame but don't know how to apply it to specific variable.

`fil<- filter(h2004, cq15>=12 & cq15<=14)`

I think my subsetting `(cq15>=12 & cq15<=14)` is wrong. Please advice. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the command. When the command is executed, the following warning message is issued:

```
Warning message:
   In h2004$crops[h2004$cq15 >= 12 & h2004$cq15 <= 14] = h2004$expen :
   number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

The reason for this is that the LHS of this command selects elements satisfying condition **h2004$cq15 >= 12 & h2004$cq15 <= 14** while on the RHS, the complete vector **h2004$expen** is given causing mismatch in length.

Solution:

```
> h2004$crops[h2004$cq15>=12 & h2004$cq15<=14]=h2004$expen[h2004$cq15>=12 & h2004$cq15<=14]

> h2004
  cq15      expen     crops
1   10  0.4616136        NA
2   10  1.5387120        NA
3   11  2.3080680        NA
4   11  0.3846780        NA
5   12  2.5767978  2.576798
6   12  5.5393632  5.539363
7   13  5.4624276  5.462428
8   14  2.6158104  2.615810
9   14 20.1571270 20.157127
```

or Alternatively:

```
> indices <- which(h2004$cq15>=12 & h2004$cq15<=14)
> h2004$crops[indices] = h2004$expen[indices]
> h2004
  cq15      expen     crops
1   10  0.4616136        NA
2   10  1.5387120        NA
3   11  2.3080680        NA
4   11  0.3846780        NA
5   12  2.5767978  2.576798
6   12  5.5393632  5.539363
7   13  5.4624276  5.462428
8   14  2.6158104  2.615810
9   14 20.1571270 20.157127
```